# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar de versión de Spring Framework en un proyecto ya existente?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

En mi proyecto tengo la versión 3 de Spring Framework y necesito cambiarla a la última versión. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso? Bueno, en si necesito actualizar la mayoría de las dependencias Maven que están en ese proyecto, dado que es muy antiguo, pero lo principal sería actualizar como ya he mencionado la versión de Spring Framework y Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe una manera automatica de hacer una actualizacion, si eso es lo que buscas.

Tal y como mencionas, primero deberias de actualizar las dependencias, luego arreglar los errores de compilación, y por ultimo seguir alguna guia oficial como esta para arreglar escenarios que se te hayan escapado: [Upgrading to Spring Framework 4.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-4.x) (lo siento, no esta en español). Y claro, no deberias olvidar volver a testear tu aplicacion entera (en este momento se vuelve evidente porque es importante tener pruebas automatizadas).